# How does Credential Provider Usage Scenarios are defined

Tags: c++, windows, winlogon, credential-providers

I'm currently trying to understand how custom credential providers are made.

I have a sample to help me. This sample especially implements ICredentialProvider and ICredentialProviderFilter for WinLogon.
My job is to implement the CPUS_CREDUI usage scenario.

However, there is a lot of things i don't get in the initial implementation so i can't even expect to do my own implementation.

All the documentation i found only explains what each part actually do. Which is the only part 'clear enough' in my mind.

The problem is that i can't connect those parts together.

The different functions seemed to be called by Windows itself. How can i know what's the caller, which parameters are used, this kind of things ?
If i knew, i might have a better understanding of the whole process.

For example :

- There is a recurrent parameter of type CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO which seems to change the way the CP is initialized further in the code.
  It seems to be first defined in the CredentialProvider constructor but since i don't know what the caller of the constructor is...
  I'm guessing it's called by WinLogon but if so, what actually define the parameters ?
- The logs of the sample always show this parameter value as 'CPUS_LOGON'.
  If this is a consequence of the CP constructor being called by WinLogon (If my previous hypothesis is true), how does CPUS_CREDUI can be called since it's post Logon ?

That's the main questions i have so far. Thank you if someone can unlight me.

I'm also open for every additional informations you would have for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Microsoft's [docs](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/B/B/3BB20108-E823-4FDB-83DC-2EFA7F353043/Credential_Provider_Technical_Reference.xps)
One of the first calls to your credential provider will be `SetUsageScenario`

```
HRESULT SetUsageScenario(
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO cpus,
  DWORD                              dwFlags
);
```

The first parameter is scenario.
If your provider is not designed for the provided scenario you can just return `E_INVALIDARG`.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, i was able to display the tile in the Credential UI.

I have a switch case on 'cpus' and i create the credential inside CPUS_CREDUI case. But the doc says i have to handle the dwFlags values passed in parameter.

Let's take for example CREDUIWIN_GENERIC which says : 'The caller is requesting that the credential provider return the user name and password in plain text'.

What does it actually mean in terms of code ? SetUsageScenario returns an HRESULT so i guess i'm not expected to retrieve the login/password and return them from here, right ?

Comment: `user name and password in plain text` is mean that you must gather these credentials and pack them using `CredPackAuthenticationBuffer` function.    
These credentials will be returned to credentials UI in call to `GetSerialisation` method.  
Your provider should not return `Certificate` credentials or other type of credentials with absence of password (even encode or encrypted).

Comment: I can personalize the tile and dislay it. Discovered SetSelected and SetDeselected and their ability to call GetSerialization.

I reproduced a 'simple' Credential and it seems to work fine with hardcoded values entered for GetSerialization.

I'm now searching how to make the tile waiting for a smartcard read (i mean how to structure it).

I'm thinking about a loop on a thread waiting for a kill instruction then it will (somehow, still don't know how to 'trigger' it other than setting pbAutoLogon to TRUE) call the GetSerialization.

Anyway, appreciate your help a lot ! I'll update later

Comment: For monitoring of Smart Cards I recommend using [`SCardGetStatusChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardgetstatuschangea) function and a separate thread. To reload list of credentials tiles I launching another separate thread that calls [`ICredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialproviderevents-credentialschanged) method.

Comment: Got it working.

I forgot to update rgbSerialization & cbSerialization in GetSerialization __out parameter.

I basically tried to authenticate with no credentials at all which is probably the reason why i had an error.

Anyway, thanks a lot for all of your help !